# Ubuntu Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: server, apache2, configuration, dotnet

Deploying an aspnetcore 6 web app to Ubuntu 20.04. Here is an article of what I am doing
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#publish-and-copy-over-the-app

Apache is now set up to forward requests made to `http://localhost:80` to the ASP.NET Core app running at `http://127.0.0.1:5000`. It worked before but now its giving me this error.

```
 dotnet helloapp.dll
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (98): Address already in use

My service file looks something like
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/helloapp
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dotnet /var/www/helloapp/helloapp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=apache
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and config like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Check what is using the port with command "netstat -tulpn | grep 5000"

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4587/dotnet
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5000                :::*                    LISTEN      4587/dotnet

Comment: Would it not be the app specified in the configuration file? dotnet/4587. It seems like its configured to run but for some reason not being able to be viewed online.

Comment: Try to kill that process and start the app again.

Comment: Yes, I was able to kill the process and run dotnet webapp.dll. What I am trying to figure out now, is why my http://website.com is not working, its showing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on chrome when. I thought my config/service file would have handled that.

Comment: After I killed the process and ran the app, I got info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

Comment: Are you trying that from localhost ?

Comment: No. I do my development on a Windows 11 Home machine, and I upload to Ubuntu 20.04 after I click on publish website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134077/discussion-between-john-ronald-and-davidjs).

Answer (score 0):

i solved the `AddressInUseException` (:5001 in my case) doing the steps listed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2001). 
Let me know if the issue persists after that.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. I developed the aspnet on my windows machine, then upload the files to Ubuntu as published. I have added a configuration file to forward request to o http://localhost:80 to the ASP.NET Core app running at http://127.0.0.1:5000 in Ubuntu

Comment: Did you check if that assigned port is in use ?

Comment: I did its my dotnet service I created. I still cant view my url online, trying to figure that one out. I developed my aspnet 6 web mvc app on my dev machine, published it and upload it to Ubuntu. This error issue is not on my dev machine

Comment: you are binding the 5000 port twice, check how to redirect the request correctly.

Comment: Ok, i will look into it. Thanks